# COMMIT OR conn.setAutoCommit(true)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, percona

I have noticed some programmer using `COMMIT` other using `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` to end the transaction or roll back so what are the benefits of using one instead of the other?

Where is the main difference?

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

over

```
statement.executeQuery(query);
statement.commit();
```

Comment: They are separate tools for different purposes.  One is not "better" or "more correct" than the other.

Comment: when using commit client on network couldn't see the new records even they refreshing thier resultset, but when set to autocommit true, it's working fine, that's my problem.

Comment: This questions show a misunderstanding of what the two methods are.  As Affe said, they are in no way the same thing.  When auto commit mode is enabled, then every statement is automatically committed.  When it's enabled, transactions are implicitly started, and commit() must be called to actually commit them (even when a transaction was not explicitly started).  commit() commits an open transaction.  setAutoCommit determines whether or not transactions are started implicitly or explicitly (sort of).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A driver changing to `autoCommit = true` after a commit is - as far as I am aware - not compliant with the JDBC spec (although you do need to read between the lines).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should in general use `Connection.commit()` and not `Connection.setAutoCommit(true)` to commit a transaction, unless you want to switch from using transaction to the 'transaction per statement' model of autoCommit.

That said, calling `Connection.setAutoCommit(true)` while in a transaction will commit the transaction (if the driver is compliant with section 10.1.1 of the JDBC 4.1 spec). But you should really only ever do that if you mean to stay in autoCommit after that, as enabling / disabling autoCommit on a connection may have higher overhead on a connection than simply committing (eg because it needs to switch between transaction managers, do additional checks, etc).

You should also use `Connection.commit()` and not use the native SQL command `COMMIT`. As detailed in the documentation of [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html):

> **Note:** When configuring a `Connection`, JDBC applications should use the appropriate `Connection` method such as `setAutoCommit` or `setTransactionIsolation`. Applications should not invoke SQL commands directly to change the connection's configuration when there is a JDBC method available.

The thing is that commands like `commit()` and `setAutoCommit(boolean)` may do more work in the background, like closing `ResultSets` and closing or resetting `Statements`. Using the SQL command `COMMIT` will bypass this and potentially bring your driver / connection into an incorrect state.

Comment: So in essence `conn.setAutoCommit(true)` is the same as `conn.commit(); conn.setAutoCommit(true);` yes?

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes, see the javadoc of [`setAutoCommit(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)): _" If this method is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, the transaction is committed."_

Answer (score 5):

The usage of `conn.setAutoCommit();` applies to the connection and gives you the possibility to execute X queries in a single transaction, or use one single transaction per `execute`

As the API describes:

```
 void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit)
                    throws SQLException
```

> Sets this connection's auto-commit mode to the given state. If a connection is in auto-commit
>   mode, then all its SQL statements will be executed and committed as
>   individual transactions. Otherwise, its SQL statements are grouped
>   into transactions that are terminated by a call to either the method
>   commit or the method rollback. By default, new connections are in
>   auto-commit mode

For a simple case:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
statement.executeQuery(query); 
statement.commit();
```

will be the same as:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true); 
statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: you should also show the difference when using 2 inserts/update/delete statements in a single method

Comment: if conn.setAutoCommit(true); then i will be not save since ACID is a priority here, but can i use conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
statement.executeQuery(query); 
statement.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true); and what will be the reflection in this caase?

Comment: @Motasem but `conn.setAutoCommit(true); statement.executeQuery(query);` will do the same as `conn.setAutoCommit(false); statement.executeQuery(query); statement.commit();` check if your `statement.commit()` is being called with success and not returning some `SQLException`

Comment: No Error found but: conn.setAutoCommit(false); then after transaction done i did commit(); i have checked the status of autoCommit mode i found that it still false !!!!!

Comment: when i started a transaction i have set conn.setAutoCommit(false); then after transaction done i did commit(); i have checked the status of autoCommit mode after commit i found that autoCommit mode still false !!!!!

what is wrong ?

Comment: @Motasem Please read the [Connection API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit()).  What it says is that to explicitly use `commit()` you should have auto-commit mode disabled, it doesn't say that your autoCommit mode will change...